# UML - How to show a class instantiated by its static main method

Tags: uml, modeling, visio, sequence-diagram

It is a Sequence Diagram HowTo question, not a HowTo code.

I am using Visio 2010 and developing >> reverse engineering from Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 / X++. Yes people its all about how to map static on UML.

My class is instantiated from FORM using at its void static main(). This calls another static method, say construct() which returns an instance of the same class.

I want to show the class (in static methods) and the resulting object separately some like the meta class runs (self msgs) and finally produces the class object which finally takes over. But how will a self msg call return a value ? How do I connect it with the resulting object of the class ? I hope I make enough sense to make you guys understand.

Note, the class is not a static class, but it has a static constructor.

Comment: I have no idea of X++ but what's the problem in returning an object value from a self call? (I guess you're talking about creating of sequence diagrams)

Comment: obviously dear, i m champion of Xpp lol, no problems in code, I am asking a question of UML and design and sequence diagram.

How to design the above described

Comment: But, as said, I don't understand your problem in a depth to be able to help. Maybe you should post what you created as SD so far and we can start arguing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to depict a call to constructor (i.e. static operation that is responsible for creating an object and (usually) returning it as a reply) then you have to use a createMessage construct i.e. a dashed line with an open arrow and the word `create` on it. While this is not directly stated in specification, usually in such case the arrow points on the lifeline box (rectangle) rather than a line itself (however I've seen information that both notations are correct).

[image: Create on SD]

Note that in this case the logic of constructor is hidden (encapsulated) which is a good idea in general.
You can find more details in UML specification in section 17.4, especially 17.4.4.1 and an example in section 17.6.5 on Figure 17.14.

If you want to use a static operation other than constructor and call it without a use of class instance you have to model class as object (after all class **is** an object itself at least on analytical level). Note that the type of message can be either synchronous or asynchronous depending on your needs.

[image: Static operation on SD]

With this approach you can provide details on how the class handles this function (i.e. what other calls does it make).
For more details see "Applied UML and Patterns" by Craig Larman, section 15.4, Figure 15.20. Note however that Larman suggest a use of `<<metaclass>>` stereotype. Yet the called object is a class (metaclass is a class whose instance is class so this is **not** our case) so the stereotype should be `<<class>>`.